# How to map id in NFS export?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have the following entry:

```
/backup    192.168.0.35/32(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

My Server_prod has a user oracle with uid 1001 and my standby server
has the same username oracle with id 54321

How to map uid in NFS export file?

When I mount it in the target, it shows 1001 uid instead of the username:

```
[root@standby ~]# df -h /backup/
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
192.168.0.51:/backup  4.9G     0  4.6G   0% /backup
[root@standby ~]# ls -ld /backup/
drwxr-xr-x 3 1001 oinstall 4096 Feb 19 14:12 /backup/ <<<<-----uid instead of username
[root@standby ~]#
```

How to solve it?

Should be

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 oracle oinstall 4096 Feb 19 14:12 /backup/
```

Comment: I believe you need to add the oracle account to your local machine with UID 1001.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to access to exports, NFS looks at the UID and/or the GID. The name of the user and group are immaterial. As the oracle user has a different UID on the server and client, the access isn't going to function.

You'll need to either set the UID of the oracle user to be the same on both the server and client or create a group on both the server and client with the same GID and set the permissions for export on the server for that group.